# Issue with my JSON callback

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am using the following code to get json from my web service while the service is outputing the correct values I cannot access it I get an error stating that its undefined when I try to alert part of the object. How can I fix this issue?

My code is below

jQuery

```
var durl =  "a valid url";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: durl,
    data:  "Pass="+avalidid,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache : false,
    jsonp : "onJSONPLoad",
    jsonpCallback: "callback",
    contentType: "application/json",
    crossDomain: "true",
    }).done(function(){ 

    }).fail(function(){ 
        $.mobile.changePage("errorpage");
    })
 });



//callback function 
function callback(rtndata) 
{ 
alert(rtndata.name);
}
```

Web service
The last few lines to return json

```
 echo $_GET['onJSONPLoad'];
 echo "(" . json_encode($posts) . ")";
```

Lastly it should be mentioned that I mapped my array so that it can return all of my results

```
 $posts[] = array_map('utf8_encode',$post);
```

Comment: does rtndata give a valid value ?

Comment: You should not be specifying `jsonpCallback`.

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools' network tab?

Comment: No it doesn't give a valid value there are no errors recorded anywhere

Comment: $post is a variable you define or are you referring  to the superglonal $_POST?

Comment: Its an array that I have defined

Comment: Just to shed some more light on the subject when I do a console log for the returned json object that is rtndata in the code I can see the information within it however I cannot access the data with the object using rtndata.name